# Trying to get data from URL returns data is nil in objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode

I am currentley trying to retrieve data from this link: http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=%E2%98%85%20Bayonet

I want the data that the link outputs when you go and click it.

Here is my current code:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=★%20Bayonet"]];

NSDictionary *test = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", test[@"lowest_price"]);
```

But currentley it returns this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

I think it has something to do with the star that is involved in the URL string, does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Your `NSURL` is `nil` because of the star character. So `data` is `nil` too, so the `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` fails.

Comment: Debugging involves checking the correct operation of all steps. There is the Xcode LLVM debugger and of course `NSLog()`. Try them first next time to locate the problem. Further if you had used a separate statement(step) for `NSURL URLWithString...` you could have spotted the problem right off.

Comment: Safari allows non-ASCII characters because it replaces them with the correct UTF, you need to do the same.

Comment: The Stackoverflow site has translated your URL into what it should be and it works: ` http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=%E2%98%85%20Bayonet`  Note the star has become `%E2%98%85` which is presumably its UTF-8 percent encoding

Comment: Use `initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` and then actually *look* at the `error` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original url, in the example code, is malformed.

First, here's the code that works:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSError *error = nil;

        // NOTE: I pruned the original '%20' in your example -- partially escaped strings
        //   are difficult to deal with.
        NSString *urlString = @"http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=★ Bayonet";

        // Now, escape the entire string
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // Looks good
        NSLog(@"%@", [url absoluteString]);
        // http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=%E2%98%85%20Bayonet

        // Run it
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSDictionary *test = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@", test[@"lowest_price"]);
        //129,99&#8364;
        // Data is weird to me, but looks appropriate.
    }
}
```

First, you didn't attempt to escape the string before using it. `initWithString:` docs state:

> This method expects URLString to contain only characters that are
>   allowed in a properly formed URL. All other characters must be
>   properly percent escaped. Any percent-escaped characters are
>   interpreted using UTF-8 encoding.

So, we do that. However, the original string in the sample code was "partially escaped". If you escaped that URL, you'd end up with:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=%E2%98%85%2520Bayonet
```

instead of

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=%E2%98%85%20Bayonet
```

... as you can see, the '%20' would itself get escaped to '%2520'.

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Please check that there is error in the URL that you copied.
The actual URL is the one that you mentioned in the comments : 
@"http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=%E2%98%85%20Bayonet"

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=%E2%98%85%20Bayonet"]];
NSDictionary *test = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", test[@"lowest_price"]);
```

Comment: But this does not work, even after fixing the code syntax. Try it. Whoever up-voted this did not try it. Error message: data: (null), 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Comment: Still won't compile, still crashes. Try it!